# Border around html div

Tags: html, css

I'm not really sure how to title this but I'm just trying to put a block across the top of my webpage. I'm using a div and setting the properties via CSS but it has a border around the sides. Can anyone help me to remove this? I've tried all of the following in my CSS but the border remains. ![enter image description here][1]

```
position: relative;
border: none;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
padding-left: 0px;
outline: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
border-style: none;  
height: 100px;
background-color: #caebff;
```

Comment: Add the HTML for your element.

Comment: do you have any url of the page you're working?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an `IMG` tag then write `border:0;` instead of `border:none;`. Write like this:

```
img{border:0}
```

OR

```
<img src="images" border="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the important tag?

```
<style>
.noboader{
    border: 0px!important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the settings for the entire body in CSS:

```
body
{
    margin : 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if the issue is having a border into the image and removing it you must make it this way.

```
<a href="docudl.php"><img src="images/doc.png" alt=" " border="0"/></a>
```

make the border=0